# how to pass a string instead of primary int key in route view

Tags: laravel, view, routes

i want to pass a name in a route view in laravel. 
for a example - 
in the web.php

```
Route::get('p/{posts}/review/{user}','ReviewController@show')->name('reviews.show');
```

it passed the primary key, the id of the *posts* and *user* . i want to pass the user->name.

my show method -

```
 public function show($posts, $user)
    {
        return view('posts.reviews.reviewshow', ['posts' => $posts], ['user' => $user]);
    }
```

Comment: where position send `string` posts or user?? Show your view code

Comment: Do you want to use for example dip for user in route such as: p/1/review/dip?

Comment: This {posts} doesn't seem correct to be in route. Is it possible that you misunderstood route() with view()?

Comment: yes. i want to use like that - domain/p/1/review/dip

Comment: i passed the object from a controller like this, $use = User::find($user->id);
        $pos = posts::find($post->id);
        return redirect()->route('reviews.show', [$pos, $use]);

Answer (score 0):

Where you call your route() method use `route('reviews.show', ['posts' => $posts, 'user' => $user->name])`.
I will suggest to rename {user} to {userName} to be more clear.

Comment: i tried it, result = Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

Answer (score 0):

First you have to change your route

```
Route::get('p/{post}/review/{user}','ReviewController@show')->name('reviews.show');
```

Then In your controller use like this

```
public function show(Post $post, User $user)
{   
     return view('posts.reviews.reviewshow', ['post' => $post,'user' => $user]);
}
```

Comment: i tried it. but error - Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

Comment: Edit my question @DipChakraborty

Comment: it returns this Illegal string offset 'name'